# Form to delete Dataobject on the Frontend won't work

Tags: silverstripe

I created a form to delete dataobjects from the frontend. the problem is it won't delete.

That's my code. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
public function deleteFromCart($ID) { 
    $fields = new FieldList( 
        new HiddenField('ID', 'ID', $ID)
    );

    $actions = new FieldList( 
        new FormAction('doDeleteFromCart', 'löschen') 
    );

    return new Form($this, 'deleteFromCart', $fields, $actions); 
}

public function doDeleteFromCart($data) {
    $cart = CartItem::get()->byID($data['ID']);
    $cart->delete();

    return $this->redirectBack();
}
```

that's my template

```
    <% loop getCart %>
        <% if CartItems %>
            <% loop CartItems %>
                $Title - $Amount - $Price - $Sum - $Top.deleteFromCart($ID)
            <% end_loop %>
        <% else %>
            Keine Artikel im Warenkorb
        <% end_if %>
    <% end_loop %>
```

Also $this->redirectBack(); doesn't work. After submitting the Form I end up here `home/deleteFromCart`

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the value of ID in `doDeleteFromCart`? Does it return a `CartItem`? Any errors?

Comment: Does "$Top.deleteFromCart($ID)" in your template effectively passes the value of your CartItem ID to the deleteFromCart method? I am not sure you can use template variables like $ID and pass them to functions. You can assess that by checking if your hidden field has the ID value at the frontend.

Comment: please provide more details. Its not enough for me to go on.

Comment: one question though: could it be that the whole thing is in a form? Make sure you don't have a `<form>` wrapped around this. In HTML you can not have a `<form>` inside a `<form>`.

Comment: Thinking when you have $ID argument to form, when it's processed you'll need to support the case where it's null i.e deleteFromCart($ID = null)

Comment: $ID returns the ID of a CartItem. This works like expected. $Top.deleteFromCart($ID) returns a form but it is not wrapped from another form. @wilr. I think it's not possible that $ID returns null because than there will be no CartItem. No CartItem = no Delete Form. or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a form, I would suggest using a link that calls an action to remove items from your cart. It is much simpler and there are less possible problems.

**Template**

```
<% loop $getCart %>
    <% if $CartItems %>
        <% loop $CartItems %>
            $Title - $Amount - $Price - $Sum - <a href="{$Top.Link}remove/{$ID}">Remove from cart</a>
        <% end_loop %>
    <% else %>
        Keine Artikel im Warenkorb
    <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

**Controller**

```
private $allowed_actions = array(
    'remove'
);

public function remove() {
    $cartItemID = $this->request->param('ID');

    if ($cartItemID && $cart = CartItem::get()->byID($cartItemID)) {
        $cart->delete();
    }

    return array();
}
```

Comment: I fully agree with 3dgoo, would have solved it exactly the same way. However, there is one part missing: it should either redirect back or be an ajax call.

Comment: yeah that's really better, but it also does not delete the CartItem. At the end this function also calls $cart->delete() like mine. But I think this doesn't work somehow?

Comment: ok that's a strange behavior. I ran a dev/build (not the first since I'm trying to get this work) and now I can delete the Items with both functions but if I wan't to add a new item to cart I receive an error(Not before dev/build). But that's another topic